# is it possible to have a timestamp column that gets updated just when one column is updated?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

One question, is it possible to have a timestamp column that gets updated **just** when one column is updated (only that column)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That would need to be done via code. Timestamp on the MySQL db will update when any field is updated

Comment: Short answer is "no"... at least, not automatically.

Comment: Of course it can be automatically, with a trigger!

Comment: @anakata if it requires you to write code (whether in your application or in the DB) then it is not automatic.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: But triggers get *invoked* automatically, which is almost certainly what anakata meant.  Otherwise, your argument could equally be applied to any form of configuration which would imply that only natural events are "automatic" - surely not a definition to which anyone seriously subscribes?

Comment: @eggyal Okay, point taken.

Comment: I don't see a requirement that it be "automatic", or not through code. Anyway, I'd think a RoR callback that updates the timestamp if the column has changed would be the thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  IF        NEW.colA <=> OLD.colA  -- has not been updated
    AND     NEW.colB <=> OLD.colB  -- has not been updated
    AND NOT NEW.colC <=> OLD.colC  -- has been updated
    -- etc.
  THEN
    SET NEW.colD = NOW();  -- update timestamp
  END IF
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Beware that your `TIMESTAMP` column does not have [automatic updating](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) enabled.

Comment: Hi Eggyal, thanks a lot for your answer! Im getting the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1:" I tried different characters as limiters (#, //, /, |) and I always get the same error :'(

Comment: @Alejandra: What client are you using?  `DELIMITER` is a client command, which is recognised by the mysql command line tool.  It sounds as though your client is attempting to transmit it to the server, where it is meaningless.  You will have to check your client's documentation to discover how its statement delimiter can be adjusted.

Comment: You are right! I was writing a migration (rails) and the "delimiter" word was not recognized :)  I just placed a character "^" between queries and placed something like sql.split('^').each do |sq|
      execute sq unless sq.blank?
    end

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You would define you timestamp column as a datetime, and then use a trigger to update it when your condition is met.

The rough syntax is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER UPDATE ON table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF(
     NOT NEW.watched_column <=> OLD.watched_column AND
     NEW.other_a <=> NEW.other_a AND
     ...
    )
  THEN
     SET NEW.timestamp_column = NOW();
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer :)